# Sequelize body-parser error in Nodejs-Express API

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have Nodejs-express-postgres API which using sequalize ORM which simply add the donors details and fetch. The adding work fine but while fetching got the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSO:10)N at position 0                       s\api-server-sequalize\node_modules\body-parser\l
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)       
at createStrictSyntaxError (E:\Noderver-sequalize\node_modules\body-parser\lib\readeProjects\red_lines\api-server-sequalize\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\\red_lines\api-server-sequalize\node_modules\raw-json.js:158:10)
at parse (E:\NodeProjects\red_line\api-server-sequalize\node_modules\raw-body\indexs\api-server-sequalize\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)    rojects\red_lines\api-server-sequalize\node_modul
at E:\NodeProjects\red_lines\api-smingMessage.emit (node:events:388:22)erver-sequalize\node_modules\body-parsreams/readable:1305:12)er\lib\read.js:121:18                 :internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
at invokeCallback (E:\NodeProjects\red_lines\api-server-sequalize\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)      
at done (E:\NodeProjects\red_lines\api-server-sequalize\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (E:\NodeProjects\red_lines\api-server-sequalize\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:388:22)
```

my route code look like the following

```
const express = require("express");
const router = new express.Router();
const Donor = require("../models/donorModel");

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(201).send("Working");
});

router.get('/donor',  async(req, res) => {
    Donor.findAll().then((model)=>{
    
      res.status(201).send(model)
  }).catch((e)=>{
    console.log('got some error')
    res.status(401).send(e)
  })
})
router.post("/donor", (req, res) => {
  const { dname, dlocation,dphone , demail, ddob ,dbgroup } = req.body;
  
  Donor.create({
    dname: dname,
    ddob: ddob,
    demail: demail,
    dlocation: dlocation,
    dphone: dphone,
    dbgroup: dbgroup,
  }).then((model) => {
      console.log("Saved");
      res.status(201).send(model);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(201).send(error);
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

and the index.js file as follows

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const db = require("./app/config/database");
require("dotenv").config();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(require("./app/routes/routes"));
//Test DB
db.authenticate()
  .then(() => console.log("Database connected"))
  .catch(e => console.log("Error:" + e))
// routes

app.listen(process.env.NODE_PORT || 3000, () =>
  console.log(`server running on PORT  ${process.env.NODE_PORT} !`)
);
```

Hope someone will have solution

Answer (score 0):

In your routes, convert the data to json before sending it as response.
e.g In the "/donor" routes, you can do this:
`res.status(201).json(model);`

Comment: Use the same pattern in the catch error block: 
```res.status(500).json(error);```

Comment: router.get('/donor',  async(req, res) => {
    Donor.findAll().then((model)=>{
    
      res.status(201).json(model)
  }).catch((e)=>{
    console.log('got some error')
    res.status(500).json(e)
  })
})

Comment: it work when i remove the app.use clause (app.use(bodyParser.json());), but again the post method will fail

Comment: got it.. fix an await before find